# Python 3 - pip install --user flag can't find installs

Tags: python, pipenv

I have installed pipenv using pip3, however it can't be found when I try to run it.

Here is how I have installed pipenv:

```
[ec2-user@ip-xxx-xx-xx-xxx newslookup]$ pip3 install pipenv --user
Collecting pipenv
  Using cached https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/13/b4/3ffa55f77161cff9a5220f162670f7c5eb00df52e00939e203f601b0f579/pipenv-2018.11.26-py3-none-any.whl
Requirement already satisfied: virtualenv in /home/ec2-user/.local/lib/python3.7/site-packages (from pipenv)
Requirement already satisfied: pip>=9.0.1 in /usr/lib/python3.7/site-packages (from pipenv)
Requirement already satisfied: virtualenv-clone>=0.2.5 in /home/ec2-user/.local/lib/python3.7/site-packages (from pipenv)
Requirement already satisfied: certifi in /home/ec2-user/.local/lib/python3.7/site-packages (from pipenv)
Requirement already satisfied: setuptools>=36.2.1 in /usr/lib/python3.7/site-packages (from pipenv)
Installing collected packages: pipenv
Successfully installed pipenv-2018.11.26
```

So as you can see it is successfully installed.

Here is what happens when I try to run my python file:

```
[ec2-user@ip-172-31-90-218 newslookup]$ pipenv run python nasdaq_scrape_sec.py
-bash: /usr/bin/pipenv: No such file or directory
```

Do I have to set a path or something?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

When you `pip3 install` using the `--user` flag is creates a directory in your home directory that is hidden called `.local`. To access those executables we want to add the bin to our path.

This should work:

```
export PATH=$PATH:/home/ec2-user/.local/bin
```